# JNA Win7 The specified module could not be found

Tags: java, jna

I have been using JNA to load a native dll and could successfully develop the application on XP.
When I try to run the same on a Win7 machine, I get the error, **The specified module could not be found.I am unable to load the DLL.**

Using dependency walker I looked at the DLL dependencies and all other necessary DLLs are present under C:\Windows\system32 which is already added in the PATH environment variable.

Am I missing something. Please suggestions.

Thanks !

Comment: Does this DLL have any other dependent DLL references that are not on the new machine? Run sysinternal's proc monitor on both systems to see which DLLS are loaded and/or missing between the two.

Comment: The list of dlls used match between my machine and the other Win7 machine. Could it be something to do with the native DLL itself ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have modified the question correctly now. Please let me know if I am missing something. Thanks

Comment: Well, you need to gat a list of all the loaded dlls in the process on the machine that works, then compare against the win7 machine.  Use procexp to do that.  I think it was replaced by a newer tool on sysinternals (forget the name), but you can probably find it on a mirror site.

Comment: Actually, found a link with all the sysinternals app here - http://live.sysinternals.com/  run procexp.exe.  If this works, I will post an answer with a picture of the process.  FYI, dependency walker will only show the *static* linked DLL references, not dlls that are loaded at run time.

Comment: Also check whether you are attempting to load a 32-bit DLL under a 64-bit JVM or vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I will check it out as suggested and update this post.

Comment: Sorry I have not tried this out yet. I am out sick :-( I will update this post with results soon.

Comment: Also, before I fell sick, I tried using both a 32 bit JVM and a 64 bit JVM on the Win7 machine as suggested. But with both the versions, I had the same issue with loading the DLL.